# No no me funciona Retrofit Android

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit

He estado siguiendo varios tutoriales y no he podido hacer una llamada a una API usando Retrofit y Gson.
Me da el siguiente error (en okhttp creo)

```
java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #4 bootstrap method
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:87)
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.skipLeadingAsciiWhitespace(Util.java:321)
    at okhttp3.HttpUrl$Builder.parse(HttpUrl.java:1313)
    at okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(HttpUrl.java:917)
```

...

```
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Bootstrap method returned null
```

Estuve más de un día tratando de buscar qué lo produce pero estoy perdido. Ayuda.

Donde comienza a darme error es

```
private void apiCall(){
    Call<ResponseBody> call = RetrofitClient
            .getInstance()
            .getApi()
            .getMonedas();
```

Da el mismo error cuando intenté

```
private void getMonedas(){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://mindicador.cl/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

El gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.2'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.8.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.8.1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré esta respuesta en inglés y me funcionó.
Agregué este código en el gradle para setear Java en 8

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
```

Gracias por la ayuda.